# Elasticsearch: How to disable field analysis for a field in a existing index?

Tags: logging, analysis

I'm using Elasticsearch to analyze my logs. 
I would like to stop analyzing some fields and consider them as plain strings.
Can I disable a field analysis for a field in a existing index?